# String comparison with several character match

Tags: c#, string, compare

Can i do such string comparison in C# that strings:
"test" and "te[smf]t" are considered equal(so that i write several letters that can be matched for equality)?

Comment: What do you want to achieve in more general sense? How many letters can you allow in between? What's the general pattern of matching?

Comment: @MarcGravell , ops...Yes, stupid question from my side, was thinking about completely different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes of course. Go go [regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
Regex.IsMatch("test","te[smf]t");
```

Comment: ops :D was searching in string comparison methods..Sure Regex...doh! Thanks.